# Finding the root and the estimation error of a fitted function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, variance, standard-deviation

I'm kind of new to Python and I want to find the root of an linear fit function inclusive errors.

I fitted the function with

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as op

def lin_fit(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

...

popt, pconv = op.curve_fit(lin_fit, U, sqrt_I)
x = np.linspace(np.min(U), np.max(U), 100)
y = lin_fit(x, *popt)
```

Then I found the root with

```
def root(x):
    return lin_fit(x, *popt)

return op.fsolve(root, 0)
```

That was no problem, but I don't now, how to find the error of these roots.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this just an example? are you planning on using the same approach for other functions?

Comment: I just want to use it for this kind of linear functions.

Comment: In that case, from the coefficients of the fit: -b/a = root, right? No need to call op.fsolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is contained in `pconv`, where the diagonal contains the variance for each one estimated coefficients, which in this case are `a` and `b`.

From the [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html) the correlation coefficient `r` which measures the overall quality of the fit can be computed as:

```
sxy = pconv[0,1]*x.shape[0]
sxx = pconv[0,0]
syy = pconv[1,1]
r = (sxy**2/(sxx*syy))**0.5
```

Comment: So `pconv[0,0]` contains the error for `a` and `pconv[1,1]` contains the error for `b`? Wouldn't the error for the root then be `((pconv[0,0]*b/a**2)**2+(pconv[1,1]/a)**2)**0.5` (Gaussian propagation of uncertainty)? And if it is so, how do I get the values for 'a' and b`?

Comment: @LinoschArtox Yes... but please, just check this equation for error propagation because I haven't...

Comment: Sorry for being a bit pushy, how do I get the values for `a` and `b`?

Comment: @LinoschArtox They are contained in `popt`, so that you can just do: `a, b = popt`

Comment: That is assuming that both coefficients are independent, right? As long as I remember my statistics, this is not really the case for a linear fit?

Comment: @Jblasco Thank you for the feedback. I've updated the answer adding more mathematical background...

Comment: @LinoschArtox Please, consider the updated answer to calculate the error estimation...